# Cannot build Android app - Duplicate zip entry

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

I have an Ionic 3 app which gives me the following error when I'm trying to build it:

`Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\zxy\Desktop\mobile_apps\newone\CourierManager\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\zxy\Desktop\mobile_apps\newone\CourierManager\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\8.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [8.jar:ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/DefaultClass.class]))`

My dependencies in `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
  implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
  compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
  compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:11.0.1"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26+"
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+"
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

Is there any way I can fix this without removing and adding android platform?

Comment: This `build.gradle` does not seem to match the error message, there is no package `ch.qos.logback`, unless adding eg. `cordova-plugin-logtofile` or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and was not related to the build.gradle. I had an older version of background geolocation plugin which I updated. But it seems that it kept some dependencies to it which clashed with the new plugin. I had to manually remove it from properties.gradle.